# Edit question to remove my upvote?

Tags: discussion

Is it frowned upon to edit a question that you previously upvoted, but later realized was not worthy, to reset the grace period and remove your upvote? Also, is this possible or does another user have to edit the question?

**Background:**

I upvoted a question (which I'd rather not link to) because; It was asked by a newer user, the question and code were well formatted, it had received some upvoted answers and I believed the problem was related to logic and not syntax.

I later came back to the question and noticed an answer that suggested the problem was pure syntax, the answer-er also proposed a superfluous solution. So I downvoted the answer and left a comment explaining why. To my surprise the OP then accepted the answer with a score of -1 and said the answer worked.

I then looked over the question again and realized it was a syntax issue. So, I would now like to remove my upvote. I don't want to downvote the question just remove my upvote.

Comment: See if there's something you can edit to improve the quality. Even if it's something minor. Since you have 2k rep, you're not bound to a minimum edit length.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's what I was thinking, I just didn't know if editing, even if it's a good edit, to remove an upvote is frowned upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's something to edit that will actually improve the answer, go for it.

However, if there's nothing to improve, I don't like making edits just to  be able to change my vote. I'd rather drop a comment explaining the problems in the answer and warn future users.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I added another answer to the question expressing the real issues with OP's code. There are edits I could make to improve the question, I just didn't know if someone was going to see that my edit coincided with the removal of an upvote and have it somehow negatively impact me.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Edits that improve the post should be done, regardless of the fact that you want to change your vote. Consider them as two separated things (again, if it really improves the post).

Comment: I see what you're saying, the edit should be done regardless and if it just so happens to reset the grace period, then why not undo my vote.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I'm just saying that useless edits should be avoided. But if you have a good edit, go for it and release your vote.